# Error using GULP: ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(cb)

Tags: javascript, gulp, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have this message when i try to watch the task list in GULP by Sublime Text. This code has to minify css and js files. Usually, we used to take this kind of js gulp file to minify this files, but the code has not working on other computer.

The error said this in sublime-gulp.log:

```
fs.js:153
    throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(cb);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
    at makeCallback (fs.js:153:11)
    at Object.unlink (fs.js:1125:14)
    at requireGulp (C:\Users\sopor\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Gulp\write_tasks_to_cache.js:30:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sopor\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Gulp\write_tasks_to_cache.js:83:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}
```

This is my code:

```js
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 20;
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');
var penthouse = require('penthouse');
var fs = require('fs');
gulp.task("load1", function() {
    return gulp.src(["images/assets/js/load1.js"]).pipe(concat("load1.min.js")).pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest("images/assets/js/min/"))
}), 
gulp.task("scripts1", function() {
    return gulp.src(["images/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js", "images/assets/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js", "images/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", "images/assets/js/jquery.validationEngine.js", "images/assets/js/jquery.validationEngine-es.js", "images/assets/js/inicio.js"]).pipe(concat("scripts1.min.js")).pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest("images/assets/js/min/"))
}), 
gulp.task("scripts2", function() {
    return gulp.src(["images/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js", "images/assets/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js", "images/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", "images/assets/js/jquery.validationEngine.js", "images/assets/js/jquery.validationEngine-es.js", "images/assets/js/tpvadyen.js"]).pipe(concat("scripts2.min.js")).pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest("images/assets/js/min/"))
}), 
gulp.task("scripts3", function() {
    return gulp.src(["images/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js", "images/assets/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js", "images/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", "images/assets/js/jquery.validationEngine.js", "images/assets/js/jquery.validationEngine-es.js"]).pipe(concat("scripts3.min.js")).pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest("images/assets/js/min/"))
}), 
gulp.task("scripts5", function() {
    return gulp.src(["images/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js", "images/assets/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js", "images/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", "images/assets/js/jquery.validationEngine.js", "images/assets/js/jquery.validationEngine-es.js", "images/assets/js/lib.tpv2.js"]).pipe(concat("scripts5.min.js")).pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest("images/assets/js/min/"))
}), 
gulp.task("css", function() {
    return gulp.src(["images/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "images/assets/vendor/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css", "images/assets/vendor/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css", "images/assets/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css", "images/assets/css/main.css", "images/assets/css/jquery.rating.css"]).pipe(concat("styles.min.css")).pipe(minify({
        keepSpecialComments: 0
    })).pipe(gulp.dest("images/assets/css/min/"))
}), 
gulp.task("cssfp", function() {
    return gulp.src(["images/assets/css/fp.css"]).pipe(concat("fp.min.css")).pipe(minify()).pipe(gulp.dest("images/assets/css/min/"))
}), 
gulp.task("criticalCSSfp", function() {
    penthouse({
        url: "https://www.pymescomercial.com/formas-de-pago",
        css: "images/assets/css/min/styles.min.css",
        width: 1280,
        height: 1280,
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)",
        timeout: 1e5
    }, function(s, e) {
        s && console.log(s), require("fs").writeFile("application/views/inline/in_formas-de-pago.css", e)
    })
}), 
gulp.task("criticalCSSall", function() {
    criticalPages.map(function(i) {
        penthouse({
            url: i.url,
            css: "images/assets/css/min/styles.min.css",
            width: 1300,
            height: 900,
            keepLargerMediaQueries: !1,
            userAgent: "Penthouse Critical Path CSS Generator",
            timeout: 6e5,
            propertiesToRemove: ["(.*)transition(.*)", "cursor", "pointer-events", "(-webkit-)?tap-highlight-color", "(.*)user-select"],
            puppeteer: {
                getBrowser: void 0
            }
        }, function(s, e) {
            s && console.log(s), fs.writeFileSync("application/views/inline/" + i.name + ".css", e)
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Dumping a wall of unformatted code is not going to convince anyone to help you. Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Does `gulp` do something different if Sublime executes it versus running it in the console? Are you using some sort of `gulp` plugin for Sublime that's not doing the right thing somehow? Your question as written sounds like it has everything to do with `gulp` and nothing whatsoever to do with Sublime. The editor you use to create your files has no bearing on what other tools do with the files you make when you're done.

Comment: @OdatNurd from the error message, it looks like they're using [this plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Gulp).

Comment: @MattDMoAhh ok; I think it's still a good idea to verify if running `gulp` manually works or generates the same error to narrow the focus a bit. I only delved into the code a bit, but it looks like it's mostly just executing `gulp` for you and capturing errors in a log.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the node_modules dir. I tried to reinstall in the project directory and gulp is working perfectly.

Thanks everyone!